# Oracle Trace File Browsers?

Tags: sql, oracle, trace

Can anyone recommend a graphical tool to make browsing Oracle SQL Trace files easier?

TKProf is great for summary info, but lately I am needing more detail on a specific run of a statement and end up going back to the trace file directly. Summarization and filtering would be pluses, but mainly looking for something with some basic drill down into detail for each statement.

I stumbled upon the trace file browser in SQL Developer 1.5.5. It would be perfect if it didn't take minutes to load up multi-megabyte files.

I have Toad 9.x but I can't seem to invoke the utilities for viewing trace files, possible I don't have that option licensed. Like so many features I find hints about it in the online help but can't seem to find the menu selections they mention in the help file or a clear connection to what needs to be licensed to enable the feature.

Do you have any suggestions for any other tools I should investigate?

Comment: I visited the MethodR site yesterday and saw their suite of tools which include a trace file lister, trace file browser, and data miner utilities. They are command line but look like they can help drill down quickly to the most important parts of the traces. http://method-r.com/software/mrtools Would love to hear from anyone that has used them.

Comment: I have started using Christian Antognini TVD XTAT program. It is not an interactive graphical browser but does provide HTML output with cross reference links, etc. Much nicer and more complete than a TKPROF listing. 

http://antognini.ch/2009/04/tvdxtat-40-beta-9/

Comment: Our Method R Profiler can process a 67MB trace file in about 2.3 seconds on my MacBook Pro. The Profiler produces an HTML file that guides your trace file analysis. Our Method R Tools graphical app running our skew analyzer product (mrskew) processes the same file in about 9.3 seconds. The Method R Trace extension for Oracle SQL Developer can be configured to integrate with our other tools so you can reach them easily from your IDE. http://method-r.com

Answer (score 3):

[Allround Automations](http://www.allroundautomations.com/)' PL/SQL Developer has a GUI for viewing traces.   I've only used it for small traces myself but it seems pretty quick.

There is a trial version available for download from their website, I would recommended trying it out and seeing how it works for you.  My company has bought us licenses and frankly, if you are developing PL/SQL, this is the best tool available.  TOAD might be better for the DBA, but for programming, this is your best friend.

Comment: +1 for "Programmer's best friend" - PL/SQL Developer is indeed very good, and so much cheaper than TOAD.

Comment: can you tell me where is that GUI for this, this could help me in my problem too :)